# How to create dynamic IF statements without using 'eval' in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to build an IF statement in PHP using some options that are coming from the Database.

Let's say I get an array like this from the DB:

```
$db = [
    'number1' => [
        '<= 5',
        '&&'
    ],
    'number2' => [
        '> 200',
        '&&'
    ],
    'number3' => [
        '= 1',
        '||'
    ],
    'number3' => [
        '= 2',
        '||'
    ],
];
```

I'd like to translate it into this:

```
if ($data['number1'] <= 5 && 
    $data['number2'] > 200 &&
    ($data['number3'] == 1 || 
     $data['number3'] == 2
    )) {
    // do something
}
```

Of course, I'd start it by doing a foreach and putting the KEYs of the array into the `$data['']` array. However, I'm pretty unsure how can I put the logical operators and everything else in place.

Can anyone give me an idea please?

Comment: It becomes complex as you can mix `and` and `or` logic, what if you would like brackets to say `x and (y or z)`.

Comment: Are you sure about that starting structure? You can't have two of the same key (`number3`).

Comment: @NigelRen Yes exactly it gets pretty complicated, that's why I was wondering how people usually solve this issue.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Actually that's by design, but you're right it's not looking ok inside an array. I just wanted to make a point that I need a solution that covers the case when there are 2 of the same conditions with different values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always better to sanitize data that comes from MySQL or any user produced data, instead of using `eval()`. For your case, I would suggest having your data split into:

- Operator
- Operand
- Next Logic

And then compare it with the existing ones and then use that. To start with, you can do:

```
if ($operator == ">=")
  if ($operand >= $value)
```

Or something similar to build it **recursively** - this is the key. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sounds quite strange, but I've tried small code example:
https://3v4l.org/h21gv

```
<?php

$arr = [
    'number1' => [
        'value' => 2,
        'comparator' => '<=',
        'compareTo' => 5,
        'next' => '&&'
    ],
    'number2' => [
        'value' => 230,
        'comparator' => '>',
        'compareTo' => 200,
        'next' => '&&'
    ],
    'number3' => [
        'value' => 1,
        'comparator' => '==',
        'compareTo' => 1,
        'next' => '||'
    ],
    'number3' => [
        'value' => 2,
        'comparator' => '==',
        'compareTo' => 2,
        'next' => '||'
    ],
];



function comparator(array $ar) {
    $i = 0;
    $m = count($ar);
    $last = true;
    foreach ($ar as $compare) {
        $i++;
        switch($compare['comparator']) {
            case '<=':
                $bool = $compare['value'] <= $compare['compareTo'];
                break;
            case '>':
                $bool = $compare['value'] > $compare['compareTo'];
                break;
            case '==':
                $bool = $compare['value'] == $compare['compareTo'];
                break;
        }
        if ($i < $m) {
            switch($compare['next']) {
            case '||':
                $last = $last || $bool;
                break;
            case '&&':
                $last = $last && $bool;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $last;
}

var_dump(comparator($arr));
```

Comment: The 'comparator' in your last part of your test array has only 1 '='

Comment: @NigelRen thanks, had a typo also in switch, didnt notice this one